# Jquery, get position of element inside overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I'm actually fixing some stuff on this [website](http://info.canvas.co.id/)

Due to an issue on IOS i had to modify the actual code, to be able to have a full background image with a fixed position. (not updated yet on the hosting, you can see the actual issue i'm talking about, 20 august 2014).

I found the solution from [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/page/2/)

```
html { 
    background: url(path-to-img) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body
{
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This solution impacted on my javascript. Where i had to calculate positions with Jquery offset()

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element **relative to the document**.
>
> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element **relative to the offset parent.**

So for example my last block is at 6000px from the top, if i'm scrolling halfway and reloading the page it will tell me that my last block is at 3000px. Since the position is relative to the document it is explaining why. I guess the position should be relative to the body.

Does someone would have a solution as easy as offset but that can calculate the position inside the overflow?

I thought about calculating each height of block and make a summation for each of them. But i wish there is better than that.

**Update :**

Here the javascript :

```
alert($('#contact').offset().top+' - '+$('#contact').position().top);
```

in its context, one of script that need to work with the positions:

```
var pos_contact = $('#contact').offset().top - 100;
var pos_end_contact = $('#contact').offset().top + $('#contact').height() - 100;

if(pos_contact < $(this).scrollTop()){
    $('.menu-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#menu-contact').addClass('active');
    var width_menu_slide = $('#menu-contact').width() + 30;
    var pos_menu_slide = $('#menu-contact').offset().left - 1;
    $('#slide-to-active').css({'left' : pos_menu_slide+'px', 'width' : width_menu_slide+'px'});
}
```

Comment: You're trying to get the offset of what in relative to what exactly? Also if you could post your javascript that would be helpful.

Comment: it is relative to the body, so not to the document. okay i'll update the post.

Comment: i dont really get what you want to accomplish.. offset().top is always the same no matter if you scroll down or not.

Comment: You have to understand that offset is relative to document. Since html tag has a property of overflow hidden, offset will have a different position if you reload at a different scroll position.

The only reason i'm doing that (i don't really appreciate to do that) is because IOS does not work well with full background image with a fixed position.

Comment: If you scroll it will not change indeed, only if you reload at the actual scrolled position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for a better answer.

One of the solution i was talking about is to do a summation of the previous block's height.

here the implementation of that solution in its context. It seems to work like this.

```
var pos_home = $('#welcome').height() - 100;
var pos_end_home = pos_home + $('#home').height() - 101;

var pos_about = pos_end_home + 1;
var pos_end_about = pos_about + $('#about').height() - 101;

var pos_process = pos_end_about + 1;
var pos_end_process = pos_process + $('#process').height() - 101;

var pos_service = pos_end_process + 1;
var pos_end_service = pos_service + $('#service').height() - 101;

var pos_portfolio = pos_end_service + 1;
var pos_end_portfolio = pos_portfolio + $('#portfolio').height() + $('#custom-theme').height() - 101;

var pos_contact = pos_end_portfolio + 1;
```

If any one has a better answer to that i would be glad to take it.